Unity2D. Не появляются враги
Враги не появляются, но при это в консоли нет ошибок. Помогите пожалуйста
Скрипт появления врагов:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemySpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject enemyPrefab;
    private PlayerRoomPlacer playerRoomPlacer;
    public int maxEnemiesPerRoom = 3;
    public int minEnemiesPerRoom = 1; // Минимально возможное количество врагов

    private RoomFirstDungeonGenerator dungeonGenerator;

    private void Start()
    {
        dungeonGenerator = FindObjectOfType<RoomFirstDungeonGenerator>();
        playerRoomPlacer = FindObjectOfType<PlayerRoomPlacer>();
        dungeonGenerator.OnRoomGenerated += SpawnEnemiesInRoom;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        dungeonGenerator.OnRoomGenerated -= SpawnEnemiesInRoom;
    }

    private void SpawnEnemiesInRoom(GameObject room)
    {
        // Проверяем, является ли текущая комната комнатой игрока
        if (room == playerRoomPlacer.GetPlayerRoom())
        {
            return; // Пропускаем спавн врагов в комнате игрока
        }

        // Выбираем случайное количество врагов в пределах от минимального до максимального
        int enemiesCount = Random.Range(minEnemiesPerRoom, maxEnemiesPerRoom + 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < enemiesCount; i++)
        {
            // Генерируем случайную позицию спавна в пределах комнаты
            Vector3 spawnPosition = room.transform.position;
            spawnPosition.x += Random.Range(-1f, 1f);
            spawnPosition.y += Random.Range(-1f, 1f);

            GameObject enemy = Instantiate(enemyPrefab, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            enemy.transform.SetParent(room.transform);
            dungeonGenerator.enemies.Add(enemy);
        }
    }
}

Скрипт генерации подземелья:
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

public class RoomFirstDungeonGenerator : SimpleRandomWalkDungeonGenerator
{
    [SerializeField]
    private int minRoomWidth = 4, minRoomHeight = 4;
    [SerializeField]
    private int dungeonWidth = 20, dungeonHeight = 20;
    [SerializeField]
    [Range(0, 10)]
    private int offset = 1;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool randomWalkRooms = false;

    public delegate void RoomGeneratedDelegate(GameObject room);
    public event RoomGeneratedDelegate OnRoomGenerated;

    public List<GameObject> rooms = new List<GameObject>(); // Список сгенерированных комнат

    public List<GameObject> enemies { get; private set; } // List to store spawned enemies

    public bool HasGeneratedNewRoom { get; private set; } // Свойство, указывающее, была ли сгенерирована новая комната

    protected override void RunProceduralGeneration()
    {
        CreateRooms();
    }

    private void CreateRooms()
    {
        enemies = new List<GameObject>(); // Инициализировать список enemies

        var roomsList = ProceduralGenerationAlgorithms.BinarySpacePartitioning(new BoundsInt((Vector3Int)startPosition, new Vector3Int(dungeonWidth, dungeonHeight, 0)), minRoomWidth, minRoomHeight);

        HashSet<Vector2Int> floor = new HashSet<Vector2Int>();

        if (randomWalkRooms)
        {
            floor = CreateRoomsRandomly(roomsList);
        }
        else
        {
            floor = CreateSimpleRooms(roomsList);
        }


        List<Vector2Int> roomCenters = new List<Vector2Int>();
        foreach (var room in roomsList)
        {
            GameObject roomObject = new GameObject("Room (" + rooms.Count + ")");
            roomObject.transform.position = room.center;
            rooms.Add(roomObject);

            roomCenters.Add((Vector2Int)Vector3Int.RoundToInt(room.center));

            OnRoomGenerated?.Invoke(roomObject);
        }

        HashSet<Vector2Int> corridors = ConnectRooms(roomCenters);
        floor.UnionWith(corridors);

        tilemapVisualizer.PaintFloorTiles(floor);
        WallGenerator.CreateWalls(floor, tilemapVisualizer);

        HasGeneratedNewRoom = true; // Устанавливаем флаг HasGeneratedNewRoom в true после генерации комнаты

    }

    private HashSet<Vector2Int> CreateRoomsRandomly(List<BoundsInt> roomsList)
    {
        HashSet<Vector2Int> floor = new HashSet<Vector2Int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < roomsList.Count; i++)
        {
            var roomBounds = roomsList[i];
            var roomCenter = new Vector2Int(Mathf.RoundToInt(roomBounds.center.x), Mathf.RoundToInt(roomBounds.center.y));
            var roomFloor = RunRandomWalk(randomWalkParameters, roomCenter);
            foreach (var position in roomFloor)
            {
                if(position.x >= (roomBounds.xMin + offset) && position.x <= (roomBounds.xMax - offset) && position.y >= (roomBounds.yMin - offset) && position.y <= (roomBounds.yMax - offset))
                {
                    floor.Add(position);
                }
            }
        }
        return floor;
    }

    private HashSet<Vector2Int> ConnectRooms(List<Vector2Int> roomCenters)
    {
        HashSet<Vector2Int> corridors = new HashSet<Vector2Int>();
        var currentRoomCenter = roomCenters[Random.Range(0, roomCenters.Count)];
        roomCenters.Remove(currentRoomCenter);

        while (roomCenters.Count > 0)
        {
            Vector2Int closest = FindClosestPointTo(currentRoomCenter, roomCenters);
            roomCenters.Remove(closest);
            HashSet<Vector2Int> newCorridor = CreateCorridor(currentRoomCenter, closest);
            currentRoomCenter = closest;
            corridors.UnionWith(newCorridor);
        }
        return corridors;
    }

    private HashSet<Vector2Int> CreateCorridor(Vector2Int currentRoomCenter, Vector2Int destination)
    {
        HashSet<Vector2Int> corridor = new HashSet<Vector2Int>();
        var position = currentRoomCenter;
        corridor.Add(position);
        while (position.y != destination.y)
        {
            if(destination.y > position.y)
            {
                position += Vector2Int.up;
            }
            else if(destination.y < position.y)
            {
                position += Vector2Int.down;
            }
            corridor.Add(position);
        }
        while (position.x != destination.x)
        {
            if (destination.x > position.x)
            {
                position += Vector2Int.right;
            }else if(destination.x < position.x)
            {
                position += Vector2Int.left;
            }
            corridor.Add(position);
        }
        return corridor;
    }

    private Vector2Int FindClosestPointTo(Vector2Int currentRoomCenter, List<Vector2Int> roomCenters)
    {
        Vector2Int closest = Vector2Int.zero;
        float distance = float.MaxValue;
        foreach (var position in roomCenters)
        {
            float currentDistance = Vector2.Distance(position, currentRoomCenter);
            if(currentDistance < distance)
            {
                distance = currentDistance;
                closest = position;
            }
        }
        return closest;
    }

    private HashSet<Vector2Int> CreateSimpleRooms(List<BoundsInt> roomsList)
    {
        HashSet<Vector2Int> floor = new HashSet<Vector2Int>();
        foreach (var room in roomsList)
        {
            for (int col = offset; col < room.size.x - offset; col++)
            {
                for (int row = offset; row < room.size.y - offset; row++)
                {
                    Vector2Int position = (Vector2Int)room.min + new Vector2Int(col, row);
                    floor.Add(position);
                }
            }
        }
        return floor;
    }
}

Скрипт перемещения врага в комнату подземелья:
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class PlayerRoomPlacer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private RoomFirstDungeonGenerator generator;
    private Player player;

    private bool hasPlacedPlayer = false;

    void Start()
    {
        generator = FindObjectOfType<RoomFirstDungeonGenerator>();
        player = FindObjectOfType<Player>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Проверяем, была ли уже сгенерирована новая комната
        if (generator.HasGeneratedNewRoom)
        {
            // Если да, то перемещаем игрока в центр комнаты
            if (!hasPlacedPlayer)
            {
                TeleportPlayerToRoomCenter();
                hasPlacedPlayer = true;
            }
        }
    }

    void TeleportPlayerToRoomCenter()
    {
        // Получаем первую комнату
        GameObject room = generator.rooms[0];

        // Помещаем игрока в центр комнаты
        player.transform.position = room.transform.position;
    }

    public GameObject GetPlayerRoom()
    {
        if (generator != null)
        {
            return generator.rooms[0];
        }
        else
        {
            // Возвращаем null или какой-либо другой объект по умолчанию, если список пуст
            return null;
        }
    }
}


Это не вопрос, а просьба разобраться в твоём спагетти-коде, в котором не возможно разобраться и который ты не можешь отладить. Это лечится только нормальной архитектурой, где нет FindObjectOfType, бесконечно долбящих в одну дверь Update и бизнес логика не висит на событиях, а для взаимодействия не городят новых флагов. П.С. комментарии-переводчики это мусор!

Могу предположить что ваш генератор уровня создает уровни до того как вы подписываетесь на событие генерации. Из примеров кода вообще не ясно где вы запускаете генерацию, может она у вас в конструкторе стартует. Поскольку все делается в одном потоке, а вы ищете объект в сцене, то возможно уже генерация к этому моменту будет завершена до того как вы его получаете в скрипте.
Вынесите запуск генерации в отдельный метод и запускайте только после того как сделаете подписку в своем скрипте EnemySpawner.
Ну либо вариант, вы саму генерацию вообще забыли запустить)
